# Intermittent view path issue with custom MVC razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewengine

We have a Sass application that we just implemented a custom razor view engine for to allow for us to have different views served up based on the current user that is logged in. In Dev this all worked fine. In Production (shared web host) however, we are having intermittent issues with it trying to serve up a nonexistent view using an incorrect view path.

What happens is that after we deploy, it works fine. Then after about 20 - 30 minutes, we start getting view not found errors. If I change the web.conf file to force an app pool restart, then everything works fine again...for awhile.

It seems like somehow, the FileExists method is returning true for these paths somehow in certain cases. Not sure if it is due to a caching issue, or being on a shared host, webfarm, multiple requests for the same page at the same time getting the results from FileExists crossed, etc??? I have no idea.

Error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The file '/Areas/OrderMgmt/Views/HH/ManageOrders/Pickup.cshtml' does not exist.
```

In the above case, that view does not exist, it is in the _Base folder: `/Areas/OrderMgmt/Views/HH/ManageOrders/Pickup.cshtml`

Below is the custom view engine code:

```
{
//http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/
public class MulitTenantRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public const string baseFolderPath = "_Base";

    public MulitTenantRazorViewEngine()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        MasterLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/%1/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/_Base/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        var PassedController = controllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        Debug.Assert(PassedController != null, "PassedController != null");
        return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, GetTenantViewPath(partialPath, PassedController));
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var PassedController = controllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        Debug.Assert(PassedController != null, "PassedController != null");
        return base.CreateView(controllerContext, GetTenantViewPath(viewPath, PassedController), GetTenantViewPath(masterPath, PassedController));
    }

    protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        var PassedController = controllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        Debug.Assert(PassedController != null, "PassedController != null");
        var tenantViewPath = GetTenantViewPath(virtualPath, PassedController);

        var isFound = base.FileExists(controllerContext, tenantViewPath);
        _logger.Debug(String.Format("Is Found: {0} Path: {1}.", isFound.ToString(), tenantViewPath));

        return isFound;
    }

    private string GetTenantViewPath(string virtualPath, BaseController PassedController)
    {
        string strReplacementString = "";

        if (PassedController == null)
        {
            strReplacementString = baseFolderPath;
        } 

        else if(PassedController.User == null) {
            strReplacementString = baseFolderPath;
        } 
        else 
        {
            strReplacementString = PassedController.User.CurrentAccountCode ?? baseFolderPath;
        }


        return virtualPath.Replace("%1", strReplacementString);
    }

    private readonly ILog _logger;
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you reword your question and choose better tags. A custom view engine has nothing to do with .NET routing.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that in release mode caching is used which causes the issues I had. You need to override the FindView and FindPartialView methods as well and set the useCache to false:

```
//to not used Cached paths. see one of the comments here: http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/
        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, false);
        }

        //to not used Cached paths. see one of the comments here: http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/25/multi-tenant-architecture-with-asp-net-mvc-4/
        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
        {
            return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, false);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks **a lot**! We had exactly the same scenario and my colleague just stumbled upon your answer which seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: Dude, you need to be knighted by the queen! Thank you so much @ChadRichardson!!

Comment: @ProxyTech Glad it helped you!

Comment: Did you investigate a way to retain caching? I have the same issue and turning off caching will fix my immediate problem, but I am concerned about performance. It would be nice to find a way to get the cache to return the correct path.